# Xcode Beginner: how link UITableView in Xcode story.boared to UITableView.h & .m code impelmantion class

Tags: ios, xcode

I built a table view using Xcode interface buidler. In this table there is a textfield which users could edit. I would need to know when user edited the textfield to save these changes.
I know in order to get the event, I might need to use UITableViewControler. So I created UITableViewControler .h & .m file, and in the identity inspector I set the class to my UITableViewControler, however, when I ran my application, table where blank. it lost all the changes that I made using interface builder.
hence, how would I link my table to my .h .m UITableViewControler.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking. Please can you add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:
go to identity inspector -> set class.